# How to grab index of enum value?

Tags: typescript, lodash

There is an enum:

```
export enum MY_ENUM {
  numberOne = 'one',
  numberTwo = 'two',
}
```

And a method to grab the index of a given value:

```
const x = values(MY_ENUM).indexOf('two');
```

With TypeScript 3.5.3 it worked, with 4.0.3 it throws:

```
Type error: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MY_ENUM'
```

How to fix it?

Comment: What function is `values`? I've pasted it into the typescript playground ([here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwLIE0D6BRAOQFUM4BvAKDjhVQCNgoB5RYOAXjgHIJWuAaKjTQMoAFQDuEDtxhSBFAL4UAxrwDO8EDIBuAQwA2yYOoAU2fMQwBKAHQBLRABNQTAGamuciF2sBuIA)) and it says that values is not found

Comment: This depends entirely on the definition of `values()`.  I'd love to see a [mcve] of this, but my guess is that you should widen the result of `values(MY_ENUM)` to `string[]` before calling `indexOf('two')`... but ideally you wouldn't use an `enum` unless you treat the values as opaque things (e.g., `values(MY_ENUM).indexOf(MY_ENUM.numberTwo)`)

Comment: values is lodash function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you just get the keys from the `enum`?

e.g.

```
enum MY_ENUM {
  numberOne = 'one',
  numberTwo = 'two',
}
const position = Object.keys(MY_ENUM)
  .map((k) => MY_ENUM[k])
  .indexOf('one');
```